# Jface Dialog, How to retrieve correctly what button pressed the user?

Tags: java, eclipse, jface, rcp

I'm having troubles with a custom Dialog in Eclipse.

in the first place, I created a Class that extend Dialog.

```
    public class ModificarGrupoBCDialog extends Dialog {

    private static final int CANCELAR = 999;
    private static final int MODIFICAR = 1;
    ...
```

somewhere I create the buttons...

```
    protected void createButtonsForButtonBar(Composite parent) {
    this.createButton(parent, MODIFICAR, "Modificar", true);
    this.getButton(MODIFICAR).setEnabled(puedeAltaGrupoBC());
    this.bt_ok = this.getButton(MODIFICAR);

    this.createButton(parent, CANCELAR, "Cancelar", false);

    Display display = window.getShell().getDisplay();
    Image image = new Image(display, ModificarGrupoBCDialog.class.getResourceAsStream("/icons/modificar.png"));
    this.getButton(MODIFICAR).setImage(image);
    image = new Image(display, ModificarGrupoBCDialog.class.getResourceAsStream("/icons/cancelar.png"));
    this.getButton(CANCELAR).setImage(image);

}
```

and when the user clicks...

```
    protected void buttonPressed(int buttonId) {
    switch (buttonId) {
    case MODIFICAR:
                // Some Code, for Change Button

        break;
    case CANCELAR:
        setReturnCode(CANCELAR);
        close();
        break;
    }
```

Finally, this is how I open and get the returnCode, in the caller object.

```
            ...
            ModificarGrupoBCDialog modificarGrupoBC = new ModificarGrupoBCDialog(window.getShell(), window, gr_bc);
            if (modificarGrupoBC.getReturnCode() == Window.OK) {
                  //... Some code on OK
            } else {
                //another code when cancel pressed.
            }
            ;
```

as you can see, after trying a while, I have to write setReturnCode() in CANCELAR switch block, is that OK ?
I spect that Dialog class automatically asign the correct return code.

May be someone could point me to a good sample.

I'm reading Vogela's blog, and may be the solution is to override okPressed() method ?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard dialog sets the return code in two places:

```
protected void okPressed() {
    setReturnCode(OK);
    close();
}

protected void cancelPressed() {
    setReturnCode(CANCEL);
    close();
}
```

so your code doing:

```
setReturnCode(xxxx);
close();
```

should be fine as long as the button id you are using does not match the Cancel or OK button ids.

You could also use the approach used by `MessageDialog` which simply does this:

```
protected void buttonPressed(int buttonId) {
    setReturnCode(buttonId);
    close();
}
```